# Geolocation.requestPermission() only works once

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air

I have an app that needs to request permanent access to geolocation permission ( also in the background ) to gather data.
At the apps start I do a permission check like so ( simplified )

```
private static function check():void{
    if (Geolocation.permissionStatus == PermissionStatus.GRANTED){
        onPermGranted();
    }else{

        _geo = new Geolocation();
        _geo.addEventListener(PermissionEvent.PERMISSION_STATUS, onPermission );
        try {
             _geo.locationAlwaysUsePermission = true;
             _geo.requestPermission();
        } catch(e:Error){
              onError(e);
        }
    }
};
private static function onPermission(e:PermissionEvent):void{
    trace("GeolocationUtil::onPermission: "+e.status);
};
```

The first time the app starts and this gets called and works. 
Now if I quit the app, then change the permission to "never", and restart the app, I can see that

```
_geo.requestPermission();
```

gets called, but there is no response whatsoever and I do not get the iOS permissions dialog as well.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Comment: That's correct, the user will only be asked once. You can check to see if permission has been denied and act accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system will only ask once for the permission even if you uninstall your app and reinstall it again, looks like it has a system level cache, 
Try go to **Setting -> General -> Reset -> Reset Location & Privacy**

Comment: Ok. So its best practise to have a dialog that reads along the lines: 
»You changed the permissions to "x" but this app needs to have permissions set to "y" in order to function properly.«
Right?

Comment: @zantafio yeah, but most of time, the user changed the permission on purpose, so you really need a clear reason for 'in order to function properly'. About how to architect requesting permission, you can refer to apple's official guide: [https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/app-architecture/requesting-permission/](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/app-architecture/requesting-permission/)

Comment: Yes, well, its a scientific application gathering data which is also used by interns. 
Previous experiences showed that it helps to keep things solid...